# Cuando paso una clase como argumento y despues la quiero usar, me dice cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, json, jackson

Estoy creando una clase DAO que lo que hace por ahora es traer a memoria listas de objetos desde un archivo json. Este metodo recibe el nombre de una clase y con eso deberia traerme la lista de objetos de esa clase pero cuando quiero decirle que es una lista de instancias de esa clase me dice que no puede ser resuelto a un tipo. Les dejo el codigo que tengo(utiliza jackson):

```
public List getAll(Class className) {

    File json = new File(this.path);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<className> list = null;

    try
    {            
        list = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<className>>() {});
    }
    catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarme el código de la clase className?

Comment: puedes poner cómo lo estás usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que provees no compila, realizando algunos cambios para que compile, el código luciría algo así:

```
public <T> List getAll(Class<T> className) {

    File json = new File(this.path);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<T> list = null;

    try {
        list = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {
        });

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Pero de la forma anterior, aunque no manda error, el contenido de la lista retornada no serían objetos del tipo adecuado, sino de `LinkedHashMap`.

Jackson necesita información adicional para poder determinar los tipos paramétricos, en tiempo de ejecución un `List<Tipo>` es lo mismo que `List<Object>`

Para retornar el tipo adecuado puedes utilizar:

```
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> className) {
...
    list = mapper.readValue(json,
              mapper.getTypeFactory()
              .constructCollectionType(List.class, className));
...
}
```

Y lo usuarías como:

```
List<Tipo> lista = getAll(Tipo.class);
```

---

Otra opción, utilizando `TypeReference`, seria pasar por parametro el `TypeReferece` construido en lugar de intentar construirlo usando generics:

```
public <T> T getAll(TypeReference<T> type) {
...
    return mapper.readValue(json, type);
...
}
```

Pero para usarlo, es un tanto mas extenso:

```
List<Tipo> lista = getAll(new TypeReference<List<Tipo>>() {});
```